# How do I show a small option view on clicking bar button item?

Tags: iphone

I have a requirement to pop up a small option-view on clicking bar button item, similar to this image.

How can I achieve this? Any tutorial or link is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an UIView and set for backgound you image. In this new view you can add UIButtons to let the user to select an option.

Comment: i am new bee in iphone development. Can you proivde little bit code so i can modify according to my application.any link, tutorial is appreciated

Comment: thanks for helping me !! i have added the small uiview in IB , rest all is described above !!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is available on iPhone but I know that on iPad UIPopoverController it looks so.
[Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can find source code [here](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) to create PopoverController on iPhone !

Comment: The popOverController is available only on iPad

Comment: @TheRonin: my whole application is in ios sdk =<3.1.2. how could i use this 'popoverview' api in my project? or will it run if i add this api manualy into my code

Comment: i dont think so its going to be work. can i draw custom view with xib file and load it when eye button is clicked! but the question is how exactly with shape and size of popover view can be created

Comment: i have tried another idea..i made small uiview with black background in IB and put custom button with name 'view by company' and 'name'. i made it hidden first in viewDidload method and on some button click i made it visible.